# Github - Fetching error

Tags: git, cordova, github

I'm using scandit for my qr code mobile app project. I got this issue when try to fetch from github repo.

```
Last login: Fri Feb  7 15:44:08 on ttys000
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:~ mohammadnurdin$ cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izify-mobile
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:izify-mobile mohammadnurdin$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin
Fetching plugin from "https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin"...
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izify-mobile/plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/README.md

cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izify-mobile/plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/README.md
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izify-mobile/plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/plugin.xml

skipping existing file: ScanditSDK.java
skipping existing file: ScanditSDKActivity.java
skipping existing file: ScanditSDK.h
skipping existing file: ScanditSDK.mm
skipping existing file: ScanditSDKRotatingBarcodePicker.h
skipping existing file: ScanditSDKRotatingBarcodePicker.m
Starting installation of "com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Uh oh!
"/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/izify-mobile/plugins/com.mirasense.scanditsdk.plugin/src/android/scanditsdk-community-android_3.3.1/libs/scanditsdk-barcodepicker-android-3.3.1.jar" not found!
    at Object.module.exports.resolveSrcPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/common.js:10:46)
    at Object.module.exports.copyFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/common.js:22:30)
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/android.js:40:20)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/action-stack.js:46:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:380:20)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:331:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:izify-mobile mohammadnurdin$
```

Repo: https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin

Why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to download package from Scandit [Website](http://www.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk/). After that try to install it from your local machine. There a some files missing in the github repo as you can see in your console output.